# Notifying a webservice based on table insert

Tags: asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server, windows

I have a requirement where third party software running on a desktop will write to a local database and I need to send some of that information to a remote web service. I don't have any control over the thirdparty software that is doing the `insert` but I can read the database.

My approach is to have a windows service check the local table every second for an insert, if there is an `insert` send the webservice request.  I don't like checking every second but this whole process needs to happen in a short amount of time after the insert.  Is there a better way to go about this?  Some kind of listener?  I don't think I can use triggers.

This will be .NET and SQL Server if that matters.

Comment: Look into [`AFTER INSERT TRIGGERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: @M.Ali  I don't think I have write access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SQLDependency class.  Implement the onChange method of the class to handle your processing.  The following article describes the process of configuring your environment and has some sample code for this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach

Comment: That would be good but I only have read permissions on the DB.  `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER`